# R: Accept commandline input, Show Error if it is not numeric type

Tags: r, coercion

In R Script, I need to

1. read input from command line
2. check if the input is numeric or character.
3. Print Error, if the input is a Character

I'm converting the input into numeric using

```
  a = as.integer(a1)
```

If User has entered character, a becomes NA

When I try below

```
if(is.na(a) == FALSE){
  cat("<b>Please enter a numeral to continue the conversation<b><br>"
)
```

I get a warning

> Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion

is.na returns logical value, I got this confirmed using

```
cat(mode(is.na(a))
```

How do I clear this warning message?

Comment: Use `is.numeric` to check if you have a number before doing `a = as.integer(a1)`. Something like `if(!is.numeric(a))  stop('Please enter a numeral to continue the conversation') else `a <- as.integer(a)`

Comment: No Sir, ...I tried that, ... Input from commandline is always character,  If I pass aab or 4..... is.numeric returns FALSE so can't so .....    Thank you for this though

Comment: Yes, you are right. Try with `if(!grepl('^\\d+$', a))`

Comment: Respected Ronak Sir, Thank you very much.... Your input helped me to solve this. I need to accept both positive and negative numbers.... I used your input and modified it for negative integers.  if(!grepl('^[-+]?\\d+*$', a))                                                                         I fear, I won't be able to buy you a Coffee, but heart-felt Thank you.